# jquery value in array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

i'm totally bugged from this problem... i need to know how to rewrite this PHP code, into jquery so we are making the check and going over the foreach method on other event, here is the code:

```
  <?php
            $aTc = array("c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl");
            if($_POST['formSubmit']) {
                    if(!$tags = $_POST['item']) {
                            exit ;
                    }
                    foreach($tags[tags] as $ko) {
                            if(in_array($ko, $aTc)) {
                                    $ra .= "$ko ";
                            }
                    }
                    echo "$ra";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: why are you using assignment `=` operator in if `if(!$tags = $_POST['item'])`

Comment: what do u want achieve with this code

Comment: I'm assuming he wants to check if it's null, then exit? Not sure...

Comment: I want to check if the value which is submited is found into array then to be displayed, if not...value should not show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhh... so I have almost no idea what you're trying to achieve here, but here's something.

```
var languages = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl"];

var list = "";
var selected = $('#languages').val() || [];    
$.each(selected, function(index, language) {
  if ($.inArray(language, languages) {
    list.concat(language + " ");
  }
});

alert(list);
```

This assumes that there is a multi-select drop-down field with the ID "languages", where the option values are the language names.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it cover almost everything i needed :)